# NodeJS export similar routes in on declaration

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I have this code in my /routes/index.coffee file:

```
exports.Dropbox = (req, res) ->
  production = if process.env['NODE_ENV'] == "production" then true
  if production
    mixpanelId = PROD_MIXPANEL_ID
  res.render 'connectors/Dropbox', { title: 'About Dropbox', mixpanelId: mixpanelId, production: production }

exports.Box = (req, res) ->
  production = if process.env['NODE_ENV'] == "production" then true
  if production
    mixpanelId = PROD_MIXPANEL_ID
  res.render 'connectors/Box', { title: 'About Box', mixpanelId: mixpanelId, production: production }
```

It is replicated many times for many different providers. Any ideas how to replicate this in some sort of function or array so I don't need to declare it many times?

Answer (score 0):

Configure it in your application setup.

```
app.configure 'production', ->
  app.set 'mixpanelId', PROD_MIXPANEL_ID

app.configure 'development', ->
  app.set 'mixpanelId', DEV_MIXPANEL_ID

// and in your handlers:
exports.Dropbox = (req, res) ->
  mixpanelId = req.app.get 'mixpanelId'
  ...
```